# Linear constraints for nonlinear variable relationship

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

Assume a mathematical optimization problem with two positive continuous variables:

```
0 <= x <= 1
0 <= y <= 1000
```

I am seeking of an efficient way to express in form of linear constraints (possibly with the use of binary/integer variables and big M) the following nonlinear relationship, so the problem can be solved with milp solvers:

```
when   0 <= y < 200      then   x = 0
when   y = 200           then   0 <= x <= 1
when   200 < y <= 1000   then   x = 1
```

The numbers 200 and 1000 are indicative.

Are there any direct suggestions or papers/books addressing similar problems?

Comment: this can be done w/ a couple of binary indicator variables & linking constraints.  But first, can you edit your inequalities?  right now, if x=200, the first and third are contradictory.  I'm thinking you want non-strict inequalities in there somewhere...?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I corrected the first and third equations with non-strict inequalities.

Comment: Consider posting to https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to [OR.SE](https://or.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work...

Here's how I think of this.  You have 3 states that you need to be aware of, which are the 3 partitions on the domain of `y`.  So, 2 binary variables can capture these 3 states.  In order to keep things linear, you will need to work with non-strict inequalities.  So define:

```
y_lb ∈ {0, 1} and let y_lb = 1 if y >= 200
y_ub ∈ {0, 1} and let y_ub = 1 if y <= 1000
```

so now we have our partitions set up in terms of a truth table for `y_lb` and `y_ub`:

```
y        y<200    200<=y<=1000    y>1000
y_lb       0    |      1        |    1
y_ub       1    |      1        |    0
```

Now we can easily link that truth table to constrain `x`:

```
x ∈ Reals
x <= y_lb
x >= 1 - y_ub
```